# SWT not enabled shell

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am trying to open a DateTime shell when clicking on a button inside an Eclipse plugin which extends the platform's preferences.

This is the code of the Button SelectionAdapter

```
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
           super.widgetSelected(e);
          Display display = Display.getCurrent();
          Shell ns = new Shell(display);
          ns.setLayout (new RowLayout ());
          final DateTime calendar = new DateTime (ns, SWT.CALENDAR);
          ns.pack();
          ns.open();
          ns.forceActive();
          ns.setEnabled(true);
          while (!ns.isDisposed()) {
              if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
           }
    }
```

As you can see in the following image the shell is depicted but seems to be not enabled. It is indeed not possible to select any date nor to close/resize it. As you can see the three bottons (red, yellow and green) appear gray.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried to get the shell like this:

```
  Display display = new Display();
  IWorkbench workbench    = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
  IWorkbenchWindow window = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
  Shell shell             = window.getShell();
```

But now I get this [image]

which is actually quite far from my intentions. My aim is to show a new window with the DateTime widget

**UPDATE**

I followed the Gilbert advice and defined my own JFace Dialog. 
As described by Lars Vogel in http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDialogs/article.html I created it as an extension of the TitleAreaDialog. It works now but there is still something I need to improve.

[image]

I would like to hide the big header for the title and to hide/remove the help button.
Is there any way to do that? am I extending the wrong class?

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to create a new Shell object, there are many ways to get it from Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry I think I am not getting your comment. AFAIK shell corresponds to a new Window which is what I actually want. The problem is that I can't get control of it. Is it somehow related to your comment?

Comment: please refer to Gilbert Le Blanc comment

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you're building an Eclipse plug-in, try the following to get Shell.

```
IWorkbench workbench    = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IWorkbenchWindow window = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
Shell shell             = window.getShell();
```

Creating your own Shell is not a good idea, unless you're building an SWT application outside of Eclipse.

Creating your own Display is not a good idea, unless you're building an SWT applicaiton outside of Eclipse.

What you're looking for, I think, is a Dialog for the calendar.  You'll have to extend the Eclipse Dialog class to make your own dialog.

Comment: thank you Gilbert, I tried to do what you suggested and updated the question

Comment: We can't go back and forth on this, but first, get rid of the Display code in your method.  You only code like that when you're building a SWT application outside of Eclipse.  Second, you'll probably have to extend Dialog and build a Dialog of your own to show the calendar.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'd suggest editing the comment into the answer, since it's more useful than the current body.